# How to generate .ics calendar invites programmatically with geolocation data

Tags: java, android, icalendar

I'm trying to be able to email a .ics calendar invite with geolocation from an android app that I'm making in android studio. I've got the location grabbing and can figure out how to send emails from the app, but how do I go about generating a custom .ics invite with geolocation to send via email or text or whatever. Thanks for any help and let me know if I need to clarify